# How add list of Multipart in Dto and hit with postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman, httprequest, multipartfile

**problem statement:**
to create Rest API which process List of Test Class and for each object present in list, has list of multipart pdf files,

**how I am doing it currently **

I have created below test class

```
package com.practiceJPA.springDataJPA.controller;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Test {

   private String emailId;
   private String firstName;
}
```

And controller class

```
    @PostMapping("/fileDto")
    public ResponseEntity<?> test(@RequestPart List<MultipartFile> files,@RequestPart List<Test> dto) {
        
        for (Test studentSpecificDto : dto) {
            System.out.println(studentSpecificDto);
        }
        
        for (MultipartFile file : files) {
        System.out.println(file.getOriginalFilename());
        }
        
        return ResponseEntity.ok("submited");
    }
```

I am firing this API from post man like below image

[attaching files with same key to pass in list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqUEV.png)
[Dto in form data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SDXk.png)

Api is working fine, it is causing trouble while mapping list of files with object !!!

what I want to achieve is,  get list of  multipart in same dto with key as object name

```
@Data
public class Test {
    
    private String emailId;
    private String firstName;
    private List<MultipartFile> files;


}
```

this will make everything easier , but I don't know how to achieve it, how to hit such complex api from postman

Comment: HOPE THIS WILL HELP YOU https://www.baeldung.com/sprint-boot-multipart-requests#using-requestpart

Answer (score 0):

Try to use in this way :

```
@PostMapping("/fileDto")
public ResponseEntity<?> test(@RequestBody List<Test> dto) {
    for (Test test : dto) {
        System.out.println("Email: " + test.getEmailId());
        System.out.println("First Name: " + test.getFirstName());
    }
    for (MultipartFile file : test.getFiles()) {
            System.out.println("File Name: " + file.getOriginalFilename());
        }   
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Submitted");
}
```

Update class:

```
    @Data
    public class Test {
    private String emailId;
    private String firstName;
    private List<MultipartFile> files;  
}
```

Comment: This will not work my first approach was this among 100 others, before answering u must have checked, my question clearly says how to hit from postman, because that’s the challange